# Only gtm.load and gtm.dom Event sent in Google Tag Manager - no gtm.click or other events

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, web-analytics

I am trying to implement Google Tag Manager on a new website (currently it's not online yet, only available on staging/production).

We implemented the standard GTM-Code on the website. GTM-Debug-Mode works, however, it only send the gtm.load and gtm.dom Event - nothing else:

[GTM Debug Mode Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBn2s.png)

It doesn't register any Click-Events, etc.

I never had this issue when implementing GTM on a website.

Does anyone know what the reason might be here?

Thanks in advance!

We tried a few things in the website's back, however, that hasn't changed anything.

Answer (score -1):

If your GTM container is empty.

You need to at least have one all click trigger then it will start listening the click event.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply! But you were right, I could fix it this way. thanks a lot!